# ElasticSearch - search hyphens, underscores, colons

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm connecting to an elasticsearch server via nodejs and the npm package *@elastic/elasticsearch ver 8.1.0*

To create the index:

```
        const response = await client.indices.create({
            index: 'foods',
            body: {
                mappings: {
                    properties: {
                        id: { type: 'integer' },
                        color: { type: 'text' },
                        name: { type: 'text' }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

My search query:

```
    const response = await client.search({
        index: 'foods',
        body: {
            query: {
                multi_match: {
                    fields: ["color", "name"],
                    query: 'apple:na',
                    type: "phrase_prefix"
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

This won't return anything, as elasticsearch won't search the colon (or underscores, or hyphens). If the `query` is simply the letter `a` I get the following results:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "foods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "MN8Hs38B5UePBFS0feQD",
    "_source": {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "apple:na",
      "color": "red"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "foods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "euAHs38B5UePBFS0fQEj",
    "_source": {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "apple:euro",
      "color": "red"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share your index mapping, settings, sample document and expected result? this way it would be better to reproduce your issue and provide concrete solution :)

Comment: Hello. I've edited my original post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `text` fields are analyzed by `standard` analyzer if you don't specify the analyzer, I think in your case, if you don't want to change and configure the advance custom analyzer which works on several special characters (hyphen, underscore etc), you can simply use the same query but on `.keyword` field of your `text` fields.

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
                "color.keyword", // Note `.keyword` field
                "name.keyword"
            ],
            "query": "apple",
            "type": "bool_prefix"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71994544",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "apple:na",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71994544",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "apple:euro",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            }
        ]
```

if you provide entire `apple:na` it produces single search result

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
                "color.keyword",
                "name.keyword"
            ],
            "query": "apple:na",
            "type": "bool_prefix"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71994544",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "apple:na",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Hope this helps.**